# Is there a way to have ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy.alwaysCreateSession in Spring Security 4?

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-security

We are migrating our application from SpringSecurity 3 to 4. We have our ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy bean configured to always create session (Grails notation to define beans)

```
sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)
sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) { 
    alwaysCreateSession = true
}
```

because we are using HTTP requests with **basic authentication** from Excel and other apps to interact with application and without that option, session is not created and authentication has to be done for every action instead of once for first action.

In Spring Security 4 `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` was migrated to `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy` (according to migration guide - http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html ) which should be used inside of `CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy` but we cannot find a way to setup session strategy.

The workaround we currently have is to call non-basic authenticated page before authentication, what causes session to be created and following requests will be executed against this session

Comment: `ConcurrentSessionControl` and what you describe are different things. The `ConcurrentSessionControl` is for how many session for the same user are allowed to be active at one time. You are mixing session creation and concurrent control... Those are quite different things.

Comment: So your point is that `alwaysCreateSession` does not influence session creation on basic auth? After setting this parameter external requests get session created so it gave us what we needed. Additional to that we also control how many sessions per user are allowed, but this works well in 4 when configured according to migration guide.

Comment: Yes it does influence session creation but it isn't related to `ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, those helped me to find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from M. Deinum pointed me into another direction and I have found that in `spring-security-core` plugin of Grails `securityContextPersistenceFilter` is defined with `forceEagerSessionCreation = false`. Overriding this bean to force eager session creation did the trick

```
securityContextPersistenceFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter, ref('securityContextRepository')) {
    forceEagerSessionCreation = true
}
```

This probably can also be done using configuration of Grails Spring Security Core

Source code is available here:
https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy